# Syntax error in UPDATE statement OleDb Exception in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, oledb

I already double check my SQL Statement and it seems that my SQL Statement is Error. I don't why it doesn't work. My SQL Statement is correct and It resulted to this OleDBException.

Here is the code

```
public void updateAccount(Int32 accountid, String username, String password, String isdisable)
{
     con.ConnectionString = db.konek();
     String sql = "UPDATE accounts SET username = @username, password = @password, isdisable = @isdisable WHERE accountid = @accountid";
     try
     {
         con.Open();
         OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@isdisable", isdisable);
         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@accountid", accountid);
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
     }
     finally
     {
         con.Close();
     }
}
```

Screenshots of my MS Access Table
[image]

Exception Screenshot
[image]

Comment: The error is pointing at other code, not the code you posted.  Note the error `Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement` so post that piece of code please.  You can also see that you are calling cmd.Dispose() after that line...

Comment: Well the exception (and those are usually right) is speaking about INSERT statement, your code is showing UPDATE statement. You are not showing us the relevent code or there is a trigger in your database with some insert logic.

Comment: Updated Screenshot! I got some erroneous shots...

Answer (score 5):

You are using a [MICROSOFT JET reserved word](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321266) PASSWORD.
This is the origin of your syntax error.

You should encapsulate your sql command with square brackets

```
 String sql = "UPDATE accounts SET username = @username, [password] = @password, "  + 
              "isdisable = @isdisable WHERE accountid = @accountid";
```

And for the named parameters problem.
As far as Microsoft Access is concerned, the provider Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 allows you to use the syntax above compatible with SqlServer. However you should respect the correct order of parameter placeholders when inserting your parameters in the OleDbParameter collection of the OleDbCommand

Answer (score 2):

When you add a named parameter like that, the text is not replaced in the sql query. You need to use "?" in the sql string and then the parameters will be replaced:

```
string sql = "UPDATE accounts SET username = ?, password = ?, isdisable = ? WHERE accountid = ?"
```

What you are doing there with the named parameters only works for procedures, not text.

If your command was set as follows:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
```

then named parameters would work. However you are using CommandType.Text, which is the default, and therefore you need to use the "?" in order to get the OLEDB driver to use your parameters.

Comment: Are you sure? Could you provide link that says that?

Comment: @seeker http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx

Answer (score 1):

the code for update is for storedprocedures in SQL server and may not work with access DB:

```
        string _Update_Emp = "UPDATE AlbahraniNetwork SET FirstName=@FirstName,SecondName=@SecondName,LastName=@LastName,Phone=@Phone,Cell=@Cell,Email=@Email,Address=@Address where FirstName=@FirstName";

        string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
        if (!appPath.EndsWith("\\"))
            appPath += "\\";
        _Conn.ConnectionString = (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + appPath + "Database31.accdb");

        //_Conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Abdullah\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\AlbahraniNetwork2\AlbahraniNetwork2\Database31.accdb";
        _Conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand _Update_Command = new OleDbCommand(_Update_Emp, _Conn);

        _Update_Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", FirstName.Text);
        _Update_Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("SecondName", SecondName.Text);
        _Update_Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", LastName.Text);
        _Update_Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", Phone.Text);
        _Update_Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cell", Cell.Text);
        _Update_Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email.Text);
        _Update_Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Address.Text);
        _Update_Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Make it simple and instead use:

```
  string _Update_Emp = "UPDATE AlbahraniNetwork SET " +
       FirstName=\"" + FirstName.Text + "\"" +
       ",SecondName=\"" + SecondName.Text  + "\"" +
       ",LastName=\""+ LastName.Text  + "\"" +
       ",Phone=\""+ Phone.Text + "\"" +
       ",Cell=\"" + Cell.Text + "\"" +
       ",Email=\"" + Email.Text + "\"" +
       ",Address=\"" + Address.Text + "\"" +
       " where FirstName=\"" + FirstName.Text +";";

        string appPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
        if (!appPath.EndsWith("\\"))
            appPath += "\\";
        _Conn.ConnectionString = (@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + appPath + "Database31.accdb");

        //_Conn.ConnectionString = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Abdullah\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\AlbahraniNetwork2\AlbahraniNetwork2\Database31.accdb";
        _Conn.Open();
        OleDbCommand _Update_Command = new OleDbCommand(_Update_Emp, _Conn);
```